# Why simple angular routing animation not working?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have very basic routing angular animation, but for some reason it's not working.
Animation definition is in app.component.ts <= there I have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and two links that when are clicked should route to appreciative child-component with "fade-in" animation - but the animation is not visible.
Problem reproduction: [link to stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rmtxrv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
I think the source of the problem is that `query(':enter')` is not "querying" (when I remove `optional: true` flag - there are error's log in the console)

Answer (score 0):

router animation is not triggered as there is nothing changing that you pass to `@routeAnimations` and it is only trying to run at start. it should be `[@routeAnimations]=outlet.activatedRouteData.animation` or something that is changing upon route changes. follow the [route animations guide](https://angular.io/guide/route-animations) on angular.io with guides of how to create route transition animations

Answer (score 0):

See please, I redo your example - need to add some properties to html and routes:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dypkqg

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '1', component: OneComponent, data: {animation: '1'}  },
  { path: '2', component: TwoComponent, data: {animation: '2'}  },
]

add import BrowserAnimationsModule

<a routerLink="1">1</a><br />
<a routerLink="2">2</a>

<div [@routeAnimations]="o && o.activatedRouteData 
      && o.activatedRouteData['animation']">
    <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Animation you can return own old.